# Dynamic url segments with ExpressJS

Tags: express

When I needed to add a dynamic segment to the URL, the first thing that came to mind was to try the following:

```js
app.get('/one/*/two/*/three', (req, res, next) => {
    // req.params as any)[0] - first dynamic segment
    // req.params as any)[1] - second dynamic segment
});
```

Turns out, the code above works perfectly. What confuses me, however, I cannot find it anywhere in the official documentation, and any answer here about dynamic segments with ExpressJS suggests different things, none of them suggest use of asterisks.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentation about [Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html):

> **Route paths**
>
> Route paths, in combination with a request method, define the
> endpoints at which requests can be made. Route paths can be strings,
> string patterns, or regular expressions.
>
> The characters `?`, `+`, `*`, and `()` are subsets of their regular expression
> counterparts. The hyphen (`-`) and the dot (`.`) are interpreted literally
> by string-based paths.

And:

> This route path will match `abcd`, `abxcd`, `abRANDOMcd`, `ab123cd`, and so
> on.
>
> ```
> app.get('/ab*cd', (req, res) => {   res.send('ab*cd') })
> ```